# How to count int-type 1D when the model returns 2D?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras-layer

I'm newbie to reinforcement learning. I'd like to see and understand the code that predicts Kerath's actor critic value, and then run it with some changes.

my code is simple code without normalization, backpropagation, compensation, etc.

The model returns the probability of x, y, and tile, and uses np.random.choice to get x, y, and tile_type, and then wants to store the tile_type in board[x][y].

i want code below to run without any issues.

how to change?

```
import tensorflow as tf

from keras import layers
import numpy as np

class CustomModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_hidden, max_x, max_y, n_tile_type):
        super(CustomModel, self).__init__()
        self.common = layers.Dense(num_hidden, activation="relu")
        self.x_probs = layers.Dense(max_x, activation="softmax")
        self.y_probs = layers.Dense(max_y, activation="softmax")
        self.tile_prob = layers.Dense(n_tile_type, activation="softmax")

    def call(self, inputs):
        common = self.common(inputs)
        x_probs = self.x_probs(common)
        y_probs = self.y_probs(common)
        tile_prob = self.tile_prob(common)

        return [x_probs, y_probs, tile_prob]

max_x = 10
max_y = 10
max_tile_type = 5
model = CustomModel(512, max_x, max_y, max_tile_type)
board = np.full((max_y, max_x), -1)

while True:
    state = board
    state = tf.convert_to_tensor(state, dtype=tf.float32)
    state = tf.expand_dims(state, 0)

    x_probs, y_probs, tile_probs = model(state)
    x = np.random.choice(max_x, p=np.squeeze(x_probs)) #error
    y = np.random.choice(max_x, p=np.squeeze(y_probs)) #error
    tile_type = np.random.choice(max_x, p=np.squeeze(tile_probs)) #error

    board[x][y] = tile_type
```

All comments are welcome.

I need help

error :

```
  ValueError
'p' must be 1-dimensional
  File "C:\Users\cglab\Desktop\gym-pcgrl-master\train.py", line 34, in <module>
    x = np.random.choice(max_x, p=np.squeeze(x_probs)) #error
ValueError: 'p' must be 1-dimensional
```

print(x_probs)

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[0.10243234 0.09871709 0.10629005 0.06060288 0.09389384 0.11354446
   0.13222174 0.10909032 0.09429768 0.08890959]
  [0.10243234 0.09871709 0.10629005 0.06060288 0.09389384 0.11354446
   0.13222174 0.10909032 0.09429768 0.08890959]
  [0.10243234 0.09871709 0.10629005 0.06060288 0.09389384 0.11354446
   0.13222174 0.10909032 0.09429768 0.08890959]
  [0.10243234 0.09871709 0.10629005 0.06060288 0.09389384 0.11354446
   0.13222174 0.10909032 0.09429768 0.08890959]
  [0.10243234 0.09871709 0.10629005 0.06060288 0.09389384 0.11354446
   0.13222174 0.10909032 0.09429768 0.08890959]
  [0.10243234 0.09871709 0.10629005 0.06060288 0.09389384 0.11354446
   0.13222174 0.10909032 0.09429768 0.08890959]
  [0.10243234 0.09871709 0.10629005 0.06060288 0.09389384 0.11354446
   0.13222174 0.10909032 0.09429768 0.08890959]
  [0.10243234 0.09871709 0.10629005 0.06060288 0.09389384 0.11354446
   0.13222174 0.10909032 0.09429768 0.08890959]
  [0.10243234 0.09871709 0.10629005 0.06060288 0.09389384 0.11354446
   0.13222174 0.10909032 0.09429768 0.08890959]
  [0.10243234 0.09871709 0.10629005 0.06060288 0.09389384 0.11354446
   0.13222174 0.10909031 0.09429768 0.08890959]]], shape=(1, 10, 10), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: What is it you need help with?

Comment: sry. Edited the my question

Comment: Print `x_probs`

Comment: Added the results of Print x_probs

Comment: print(x_probs) solved the problem
`x_probs = tf.reshape(x_probs, max_x  * max_y)
x = np.random.choice(max_x, p=np.squeeze(x_probs[:10]))`
Thank you